# Android OpenCV record video

Tags: android, opencv, video, recorder

I am trying to include a recording button on my camera view. I am using a CameraBridgeViewBase to make the link with OpenCV. Also I am using a VideoWriter to record my video. Here is my code :

In onCreate() method I set my record button :

```
   videoRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0){

            if (recording) {
                recording = false;
                focus.stop();
            } else {
                recording = true;
                focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()); // remet le compteur à 0
                focus.start();
                recordfilepath();
                java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(date.getTime());
                File file = new File(recordfilepath(), "VID_" + timeStamp + ".avi");
                Log.d(TAG, "file : " + file);
                try {
                    if(!file.exists()){
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                filepath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                //VideoWriter mVideoWriter = new VideoWriter(recordfilepath(), VideoWriter.fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 25.0D, mRgba.size());
            }
        }
    });
```

I have a recordfilepath() method :

```
private String recordfilepath() {

    File sddir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File vrdir = new File(sddir, "LiveStick");
    if(!vrdir.exists())
    {
        vrdir.mkdir();
    }
    String filepath = vrdir.getAbsolutePath();
    return filepath;
}
```

And finally in onCameraFrame() I use the VideoWriter :

```
if(recording){
       // Log.d(TAG, "filepath : " + filepath);
        if (mVideoWriter == null) {
            mVideoWriter = new VideoWriter(filepath, VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 30.0, mRgba.size());
            Log.d(TAG,"mVideoWriter good : " + mVideoWriter);
            mVideoWriter.open(filepath, VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 30.0, mRgba.size());
            Log.i(TAG, "onCameraFrame: recordFilePath" + filepath);
        }
        if (!mVideoWriter.isOpened()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCameraFrame: open");
            mVideoWriter.open(filepath, VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 30.0, mRgba.size());
        }
        mVideoWriter.write(mRgba);
    } else {
        if (mVideoWriter != null) {
            mVideoWriter.release();
            Log.d(TAG,"mVideoWriter release");
        }
    }
```

All the log work so I assume my videoWriter is alright. But my problem is that when I go to check the file created in the Android file manager App, it appears with the right size (varies so the file created is not empty) but I can't open it. I have the message "impossible to open". 
Does anyone might have an idea that can explain this ?